# How to implement multiple JSON schemas per JSON data column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I'm using javascript-based CAD configurators to load products (i.e. materials) to be configured into new products (separate table - i.e. widgets). My JSON data columns need to adapt and be valid for materials to be used in client-side configurators for the creation of different kinds of new widgets.

My thought is to add a "data_type" column where each "data_type" is associated with a JSON Schema schematic. This column could be a foreign key or a string as JSON Schemas could be stored in a table (a json "schema" column in a data_types table) or directory (tablename-datatype.schema.json).

At this stage, I'm thinking a data_types table would be more flexible and easier to maintain and serve schemas from. Additionally, this would enable schemas to be shared between tables and I could implement a versioning system to facilitate configurator evolution.

What are the options to implement multiple JSON schemas per column in MySQL? Are there better ways of accomplishing what I'm intending to?

Comment: What problem would this solve?

Comment: I'm using javascript-based CAD configurators to load products (i.e. materials) to be configured into new products (separate table - i.e. widgets). I want to be able to create new materials that can be configured client-side into widgets using a widget's configurator. The problem this would solve is enabling JSON data columns to adapt and be valid for materials to be used in client-side configurators for the creation of different kinds of new widgets.

Comment: This is above my pay-grade to answer, but I'd edit the question to include the context within the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit to include context

Answer (score 0):

In this use case:

> I'm using javascript-based CAD configurators to load products (i.e. materials) to be configured into new products (separate table - i.e. widgets). My JSON data columns need to adapt and be valid for materials to be used in client-side configurators for the creation of different kinds of new widgets.

To facilitate flexible JSON schemas that can be validated and used with relation to individual JSON data columns in multiple tables, the structure I'll implement is:

- JSON data is only for client-side processes. This data is related to MySQL entries that have columns and relations that are queried at a higher level. The JSON data requires a flexible architecture for client-side functionality.
- Create a `datum_schema` table. Columns might include key (id), string (name), integer (version), and json (schema) columns. Schemas can be shared, ensure backwards compatibility, and served to multiple client-side technologies.
- Tables where entries require a single JSON data record. Create a json column and a reference to a datum_schema record. In the use case, this would be configurators and widgets:

**Creating configurators**: you create a configurator and datum_schemas records. In the use case, I'll create two schemas: one for settings and one for inputs. Specific settings for loading a configurator instance are stored in a json column within the configurators table.

Configurator table entries store references to their setting and input schemas. User rights will enable some users to create only configurator entries and others to create entries and define schemas.

**Creating widgets**: as you're using a configurator to create a widget, widget json data will be the input values needed to recreate itself and a reference to its configurator record.

**Tables** where a single entry may need multiple JSON data records.

Create a separate table to store json data with references to the first table. In the use case, this would be materials.

**Creating materials**: in the materials table, an entry is made to store any higher level of queryable information (i.e category). In a separate material_data table, entries include a reference to the material, json data, and a reference to the datum_schema. If the material is used in a configurator, the json data will have been structured according to a datum_schema record created by the configurator.

Want to create new kinds of widgets? Define a configurator, the necessary schemas, and relevant material categories.

I believe this to be a reasonable solution but, as I'm new to MySQL and database design in general, I'd appreciate feedback.